# ZF2 custom function isActive() in Zend Navigation Page Mvc

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem when using ZF2.3.3 as the following screenshot shows:

[image: Screenshot]

My solution is to customize the `isActive` function in `Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc`, but how to override it when I cannot modify the ZF core?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [the comment of `Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage::factory()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Page/AbstractPage.php#L163), you can supply a fully qualified class name as the `type` option.

> ```
>  * Factory for Zend\Navigation\Page classes
>  *
>  * A specific type to construct can be specified by specifying the key
>  * 'type' in $options. If type is 'uri' or 'mvc', the type will be resolved
>  * to Zend\Navigation\Page\Uri or Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc. Any other value
>  * for 'type' will be considered the full name of the class to construct.
>  * A valid custom page class must extend Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage.
> ```

Take note of :

> A valid custom page class must extend Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage

It looks as if you can also add your own static factory however I don't think you would need to.